# What does "interference" mean when referring to quantum computation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, interference, quantum-computer

I keep coming across off-handed references to "interference" in the context of discussions of the unique features of quantum computers. I understand that these references may mean (or seem to mean) something to readers with backgrounds in electromagnetism, in particular "waves". But this background also — at least from my perspective — seems like it brings along some unhelpful baggage.

What does "interference" mean when referring to quantum computation? Specifically — without any reference to waves or any aspect of electromagnetism, and just limiting the discussion to complex numbers, probability amplitudes and probabilities, and (digital) quantum states —  what is meant by "interference" in the context of quantum computation, especially with reference to its special "power"? Or, put another way: what mathematical operations correspond to interference in a quantum computational context?

Comment: Interference isn’t just a wave phenomenon. The most general thing it means is this: when you have a linear system, the sum of two solutions is also a solution. But often quantities we care about are quadratic, not linear (the wave energy for electromagnetic waves; the probability for quantum states). Those quadratic things combine in a more complicated way and the extra terms are the interference.

Answer (score 4):

Interference usually means that certain terms cancel when quantum states are  added (i.e. superposition). This can happen since amplitudes can be negative (actually complex). In my view, this is what is exploited in a quantum computer. If one finds operations to perform on the state such that the terms representing the "wrong answers" cancel and then measures the state, one will obtain a measurement outcome representing a "correct answer" with probability 1.

Comment: So interference corresponds to the addition of amplitudes (for corresponding states), in particular the addition of negative amplitudes.

Comment: Yes, the addition of amplitudes with opposite sign such that they cancel (or at least almost cancel such that the probability to get that measurement outcome is low)

Comment: It can be constructive interference too. One of the reasons, for difficulty in implementing quantum computers is phase randomization due to unavoidable environment induced decoherence .

Comment: That's true, constructive interference is also present. Not sure what your second point has to do with this though.

Comment: It's not regarding your answer. I just added why controlling the environment induced  decoherence effect are important for harnessing interference effects to do quantum computation.

Answer (score -1):

- Interference in quantum computing lets computers work on hard
  problems faster and with better accuracy than old computers.
- It helps keep data safe by making encryption better, which is very
  hard for hackers to break.
- Quantum computing can change many areas like weather telling,
  artificial smartness, and finding the best way to do things.

Read More About:[What Is The Benefit Of Interference In Quantum Computing?](https://infoblendr.com/what-is-the-benefit-of-interference-in-quantum-computing/) from infoblendr.com